# Magento Promotions Rule

Tags: php, magento, promotions

I have the multiple stores runnning on single magento website.
For Example,
Cloth,
Electronics,
Jewellery etc.

Now i want the promotions rule like 'Get $50 discount on purchase of $500 or more from the cloth store only'

Can you please let me know what are my conditions for Conditions & action tabs?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i got the answer:-)

Condition Tab:

If total amount  equals or greater than  500  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:

```
 Category  is one of  5,6 (all category of your cloth store)
```

Action Tab:

```
      Category  is one of 5,6 (all category of your cloth store)
```

Hope this will help others...

Answer (score 0):

you will have the option to select website and store under the Rule information tab on Shopping cart rule,

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But under rule information page i find  an option for website selection only, no store selection option.